# Finding XML Element without knowing the depth of structure

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML structure with an < type> element. There is only one < type> element per structure. How will i get the value of the  element without knowing the depth of the xml structure. I need to create a method that pass in the xml and return the value of the < type> element using C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can use XPath for that.

A query like `//type` will match any . It does not matter where it is in the xml.
Of Course the query will return a list. In your case you only need to take the first element.

here is a sample:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=netframework-4.8

Change this line to:

```
nodeList=root.SelectNodes("//type");
```

some other xpath samples:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256086(v=vs.100)